# Остановка воспроизведения звука в Delphi

Tags: delphi

Собственно проблема: этот код запускает звук

```
PlaySound('C:\1.wav', 0, SND_ASYNC);
```

А как её остановить то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PlaySound(0,0,SND_ASYNC);
```